# Scrapy and DuplicatesPipeline avoid saving duplicates to db

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy

Currently my Scrapy library based spider is scraping a url (this url updates every minute with new items) and saving news list items to a database, the list is updated every hour and I am trying to avoid adding duplicates of these news items, through the use of "class DuplicatesPipeline(object):" in my pipelines.py

Currently my script is saving news items into the db, however it still saves duplicates.

Probably class DuplicatesPipeline is the wrong way to go since it does not seem to check against existing records in the database, it only checks against duplicates in current session.

Very thankful for your help

Model:

```
class Listitem(DeclarativeBase):
    """Sqlalchemy deals model"""
    __tablename__ = "newsitems"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column('title', String)
    description = Column('description', String, nullable=True)
    link = Column('link', String, nullable=True)
    date = Column('date', String, nullable=True)
```

Pipelines.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Presstv, db_connect, create_presstv_table
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem




class PressTvPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates deals table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_presstv_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)




    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """Save deals in the database.

        This method is called for every item pipeline component.

        """
        session = self.Session()
        deal = Presstv(**item)

        try:
            session.add(deal)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()

        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should:

- add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `link` in your database
- check something like `db.query(Listitem).filter_by(link=item.link).first() is None` in the pipeline

Your mechanism may be used as an optimization - if you find a copy in your instance cache, there is not need to run the query. But if there is no copy, run the query.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution makes sense. I have now made added UNIQUE constraint to "link" in the database, however I do not fully understand what you mean by "check something like db.query(Listitem).filter_by(link=item.link).first() is None in the pipeline", would be happy if you could provide me with an example.

Comment: Well, that `db.query(..` is an example actually - it's Python code (SQLAlchemy query). I mean that the pipeline should check if database contains an item with the same link as the item you it is currently processing, and make a desicion (whether to reject current item) based on that.

Comment: Something like the following? (process_item)

'try:
            if db.query(Presstv).filter_by(link=item.link).first() == None:
                session.add(deal)
                session.commit()'

Comment: Thank you for your great help, got it working:

'if session.query(Listitem).filter_by(link=item['link']).first() == None:
            try:'